# How to decide on a data structure to find similar path taken by various transformations on a node

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

I have following use case

Instance - Consider this as a black box on which transformation happens and each type of transformation changes the state of the instance

Transformation - An action applied on the instance which changes the instance's state. For example and upgrade is a type of transformation that can upgrade the version of the instance from v1 to v2

end - end signifies that no more transformation can be done on the instance anymore

so we can have following for example:

```
create (instance1) , upgrade(instance1), delete (instance1),recover(instance1), change_domain(instance1), end

create(instance2), delete(instance2), end

create(instance3), change_domain(instance3), delete (instance3), recover(instance3),end

create(instance4), delete (instance4), end
```

My goal is to find the occurence of a specific transformation path taken by all the instances.. so in above example..

```
create -> upgrade -> delete -> recover -> change_domain (1 time)
create -> delete (2 times instance2 and instance 4)
create -> change_domain-> delete -> recover( 1 time)
```

What kind of data structure would be a fit to store the data and what sort of algorithm would work for this? I am thinking along the lines of graph where edges are transformation but not too sure what nodes would be and how will be I calculate occurence of a particular path..

Comment: This question can't be answered as-is. To pick a data structure, you'll always need to know the relative sizes of things and frequency of operations.  This is because nearly always there will be tradeoffs: simplicity vs. efficiency, and efficiency of one operation vs. another. For example, you could spend a lot of effort computing a cool representation of the  operation sequences that makes queries very efficient. But if the collection of sequences changes often, a cool data structure may be useless because it can't be updated efficiently. Etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @Gene I want to optimize on the read and i am okay with write to take longer if needed. At its core my use case is basically a data analysis where there would be more frequent reads. I am okay with being eventually consistent in getting the number of transformations. The frequency of transformation on instances is not very high.. For example there is 1 transformation per instance per day on an average

Comment: Still too many details missing. What is the scale? How big are things? How many are there? What are time and other constraints? E.g. do the data need to live in persistent storage, or are they ram resident? And what's the potential for all these things to change in the future? Another question is are the sequences of transformations always about one object? (Why is each operation tagged; can they be different?) At first glance, the transformations look like strings, and the queries look like simple regexes. So the question devolves to matching a regex against many strings to find all matches.

Answer (score 0):

Assign each transformation type an 1-based index.   e.g. create 1, upgrade 2, delete 3,  ...

Let I be the number of different transformation types.

When the transformation path for an instance is input, convert to a number base I.  Call this the instance's history number

For example:

```
create(instance2), delete(instance2), end => 13
```

Store the instance indexes in a mulitimap keyed by its history number

To find the occurrences of a specific transformation path, convert it to a history number and do a look up on the multimap.

A sensible trick would be to round up I to the nearest, larger power of 10.  Then you do not need to muck around with numbers of unusual base and can employ a standard library multimap keyed with a decimal number.

Here is a C++ implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

/** Store transormation paths for fast lookup

https://stackoverflow.com/q/70818186/16582

*/
class cTranformation
{
public:
    /** add a transformation path
     * @param[in] path e.g. "create delete"
     * @return 0-based index of instance
     */
    int add(const std::string &path);

    /** Search for instances with a transformation path
     * @param[in] path e.g. "create delete"
     * @return vector of instance indices, 0-based
     */
    std::vector<int> search(const std::string &path);

private:
    /// multimap storage of instances keyed by their hustory number
    std::multimap<int, int> mympHistory;

    /// vector storage of transormation paths as they were input
    std::vector<std::string> myvInput;

    /// map transformations indices, keyed by transformation name
    std::map<std::string, int> mympTransform;

    int makeHistory(const std::string &path);

    int transformationIndex(const std::string &transform);

    std::vector<std::string> ParseSpaceDelimited(
        const std::string &line);
};

int cTranformation::add(const std::string &path)
{
    myvInput.push_back(path);
    int instance = (int)myvInput.size() - 1;

    mympHistory.insert(
        std::make_pair(
            makeHistory(path),
            instance));

    return instance;
}

int cTranformation::makeHistory(const std::string &path)
{
    // assumes there are less than 10 different transformations
    const int base = 10;

    int history = 0;
    auto steps = ParseSpaceDelimited(path);
    for (auto &st : steps)
    {
        history = base * history + transformationIndex(st);
    }
    //std::cout << path << " => " << history << "\n";
    return history;
}

int cTranformation::transformationIndex(const std::string &transform)
{
    int index;
    try
    {
        index = mympTransform.at(transform);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        index = mympTransform.size();
        mympTransform[transform] = index;
    }
    return index;
}
std::vector<int> cTranformation::search(const std::string &path)
{
    auto range = mympHistory.equal_range(makeHistory(
        path));

    std::vector<int> v;
    for (auto it = range.first;
         it != range.second;
         ++it)
        v.push_back(it->second);
    return v;
}

std::vector<std::string> cTranformation::ParseSpaceDelimited(
    const std::string &l)
{
    std::vector<std::string> token;
    std::stringstream sst(l);
    std::string a;
    while (getline(sst, a, ' '))
        token.push_back(a);

    token.erase(
        remove_if(
            token.begin(),
            token.end(),
            [](std::string t)
            {
                return (t.empty());
            }),
        token.end());

    return token;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // construct input transformation paths
    std::vector<std::string> vInput{
        "create upgrade delete recover change_domain",
        "create delete",
        "create change_domain delete recover",
        "create delete"};

    // construct path to search for
    std::string searchpath("create delete");

    // construction transformation path store
    cTranformation T;

    // add paths to store
    for (auto &p : vInput)
    {
        T.add(p);
    }

    // search for instances with a path
    auto v = T.search(searchpath);

    // display results
    std::cout << searchpath << " instances ";
    for (int i : v)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
create delete instances 1 3
```